# I don't understand how to use wait() and notify()

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm doing a simple videogame using JavaFX. I have a problem communicating 2 classes, as each one needs some stuff from the other.

This is the first class:

```
public final class GUI extends Application {

private Game _game;
private GridPane _taulerVisual;
private Stage _primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
    //stuff 
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

public void addTile(myTile r) {
    double x, y;
    _taulerVisual.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            double mouseX = e.getSceneX();
            double mouseY = e.getSceneY();
            addVisualTile(r, mouseX, mouseY);
        }
    });
}

public void addVisualTile(myTile r, int x, int y) {
    myVisualTile rV = new myVisualTile(r);
    new myVisualTile add = new myVisualTile();
    _taulerVisual.add(rV, x, y);
}
```

and some more stuff

And this is the second class:

```
public class Game {
private GUI _gui;
//more stuff

public void play() {

    int x = 100; int y = 100;
    myTile ini = _tauler.ini(); // This is the logical board
    _gui.addVisualTile(ini, x, y);
    Player j;
    int i = 0;
    while (!_tileStack.empty()) {
        try {
            if (i == _players.size()) i = 0;
            j = _players.get(i);
            i++;
            turn(j);
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("stuff");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final");
}

private void turn(Player j) {
    myTile r=_tileStack.getFirst();
    _gui.addTile(r);
    notify();
}
```

The problem is that for each turn, I want to wait until the player has made his move (method turn). That makes sense, doesn't it?

But, how I do it?

Method play() is called from GUI.

Comment: Looks like it is a classic "producer-consumer" problem. Can You try some tutorials? like [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html)

Comment: You must never block the _JavaFX Application Thread_ as that will cause your application to become unresponsive. Think in a more [_event-driven_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) fashion.

Comment: @Slaw This is how I tried, but tiles aren't showed until the game terminates, and obviously I'd like to see the tiles added as they get added to the board. So I guess that, in class Game() the while in the method play has to wait until each move (turn) has been done.

Comment: Please post [mcve] and explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: For each turn, i want to add a tile in my gridpane and I want to do that using the mouse. But the game (method play) goes straight to the final and doesn't wait to the player to make a move. I mean, this should be: For each player, he takes a tile, he adds and next it's the turn of the next player. But the program passes all the turns and then it let to make infinit moves.

Comment: You need to get rid of the `while` loop. Keep track of whose turn it is and the state of the board. When a user chooses a tile (e.g. via mouse click), update the state of the board and make it the next player's turn. Then when that player chooses a tile (e.g.  via another mouse click), do those steps over again. You can add checks that makes sure a move is valid before updating whose turn it is. This is what I meant by "_event-driven_" earlier; only perform the next step when the appropriate event has occurred.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I tried to do with wait and notify. I wanted to wait the main thread until a move was made. So the main question is, how can I "wait" until a turn is mae?

Comment: You "wait" by not doing anything. The _JavaFX Application Thread_ is already executing a loop (that's how it processes events/tasks/etc); that's why blocking it with your own code prevents it from doing other things it needs to do (e.g. render the graphics). Just listen for a `MouseEvent` and react according to the current state of the game.

Comment: In other words, think more like, "_I need to **react to** some event_", instead of, "_I need to **wait for** some event_".

Comment: Ok I get it. I must use an event listener to get when the event has got done and then continue the execution. ¿Can u help me with some example? I've found a lot of documentation and i still dont get how to do that